# Why compile button is disabled in VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, button, compilation

For some reason when I open my project Compile button is disabled. I'm in C++ file and Ctrl+F7 doesn't work, Menu/Build/Compile is disabled and Compile in context menu in SolutionExplorer is disabled too. I can build project with F7, but I can't compile single file. It used to work just fine.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Perhaps the file is not part of the project?

Comment: You opened a C++ file.  You haven't opened a project.

Comment: I have project opened and file is part of the project (I open the file by double clicking in the SolutionExplorer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem is on my side: someone in my team introduced some build scripts, which apparently work only for building whole project.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem just because my project wasn't **set as startup Project** in my solution. Setting it solve the issue.

Comment: Indeed it's so, at least for Visual studio 2017. Setting as startup project once makes it working. This is Visual studio bug itself. Minor thus.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be that a referenced property sheet could not be found. You can check this by attempting to view the properties of the project (Alt-Enter). A warning will be shown then when the property sheet cannot be found. Fix the property sheet reference, and probably you can compile again.

Note: question was asked/answered a while ago, but maybe it is useful for other persons.

Answer (score 0):

My project was using an intermediate version of a unity build (sometimes called *blob build*) where groups of ~10 cpp files are put in the same compilation unit by being included in some `blob_xxx.cpp`. The project only considers the `blob_xxx.cpp` as source files, so technically the `.cpp` I was working on was *not* a source file for the project, so the `Compile` command was disabled (this is similar to what Paulius experienced).

In this case, you need to either select the `blob_xxx.cpp` file and `Compile` this single file, or switch to a non-blob build.
If your objective is to quickly test for compilation errors, you can comment out the `include`s for all the files you are not working on.

Alternatively, you may setup your project generation script to isolate the files you are working on in a separate blob (it's up to you to define what "working on" means; it may be a manual list or the list of cpp files that are checked out in Perforce if using it).